# Geometric rotation of font character in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, frontend

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKWzbQ), and what i would like to do is to smoothly rotate each font character on its centerpoint while it translate. I'm very new to the canvas world and i don't really know how to achieve that.

I tried like this, but its seems to act strangely :

```
Draw: function () {
                //tried to add this line :
               context.rotate(Math.PI / 4);

                context.font = this.size + "px FontAwesome";
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.strokeStyle = this.color;
                if (this.id % 2 == 0) {
                    context.fillText(this.icon, this.x, this.y);
                } else {
                    context.strokeText(this.icon, this.x, this.y);
                }
            }
```

Any ideas ? Is it possible for each character to have its own rotation speed too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, text is drawn with `textAlign='start'` and `textBaseline='alphabetic'`.  So `fillText("g",20,50)` draws your single character flush left (at x=20) and allows character descenders to drop below y=50.

If you want to draw your text centered at a specified [x,y] you can set `textAlign` and `textBaseline`.

```
// text will be horizontally centered around the specified x in filltext
textAlign='center';

// text will be vertically centered around the specified y in filltext
textBaseline='middle';
```

To rotate a character:

1. `context.translate` to the desired center x,y.
2. `context.rotate` to the desired angle.
3. `context.fillText(yourCharacter,0,0)` to draw the character on the canvas. You draw at 0,0 because you've already moved the origin to x,y with the `context.translate` command.

You can use requestAnimationFrame to animate the rotation of your character.

Put the code that rotates your character into a function: `function rotateCharacter()`. Send in arguments needed to center and rotate the character: `character`, `centerX`, `centerY`, `radianAngle`.

Then create another function that animates your character's rotation: `function animate()`

Inside the animation function:

1. Clear the canvas: `context.clearRect`,
2. Call the rotation function to draw the rotated character,
3. Update the rotation angle for the next animation frame
4. Request that the animation continue: `requestAnimationFrame`

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// set canvas text styling
ctx.font='30px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

// character vars
var character='M';
var centerX=50;
var centerY=50;
var radianAngle=0;

// start animating
requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function rotateCharacter(text,centerX,centerY,radianAngle){
    // translate to the centerpoint you desire to rotate around
    ctx.translate(20,50);
    // rotate by the desired angle
    ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
    // draw the text on the canvas
    ctx.fillText('M',0,0);
    // always clean up -- reset transformations to default
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

function animate(time){
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // draw the character rotated & centered at centerX,centerY
    rotateCharacter(character,centerX,centerY,radianAngle);
    // update the rotation angle for next time
    radianAngle+=Math.PI/45;
    // request another animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid blue; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>A character rotating around a specified centerpoint</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Well thank you for your complete answer. However, I really do not see how to implement your answer to my question. 
I think I do not understand very well canvas , and I want the character rotate continuously while it translate. I just don't know how to do it, or if it's even possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to animate the rotation of a character around a specified centerpoint. I've put the code inside a function so you can plug-and-play into your project. Good luck with your project!